# How to add localStorage to my to-do website?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, save

I am trying to make a to-do website where I will input my tasks which i want to do and when I want to check what they were, I just open the site. If I want to delete them I double click. But I can't get the saving part to work I've been trying with local storage but I don't think I'm doing my code correctly.

Here is my code -

I couldn't get the output to save.

```js
let enterButton = document.getElementById('enter');
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById('toDoContainer');
let inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');

save();

enterButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Check if the input field is not empty
  if (inputField.value !== '') {
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.classList.add('paragraph-styling');
    paragraph.innerText = inputField.value + "\\n";
    toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = '';

    paragraph.addEventListener('click', function() {
      paragraph.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      localStorage.setItem('saveValue', toDoContainer.innerHTML)
    })

    paragraph.addEventListener('dblclick', function() {
      toDoContainer.removeChild(paragraph);
      localStorage.setItem('saveValue', toDoContainer.innerHTML);
    })
  } else {
    //Add to show error to type in characters and make it dissapear after a few seconds
  }

});
//Add local storage so the data isnt lost
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem('value', toDoContainer.value);
  inputField.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('saveValue');
}
save();
```

Comment: You can try this `localStorage.setItem('value', JSON.stringify(saveValue))` if 
`toDoContainer` your value is an object.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - ***[search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=localStorage+%22to-do%22+site%3Astackoverflow.com)***.  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You are saving twice in random places in the code. You need to save in the click event when the todo has been validated and created. Store the todo in an array or object and use `localStorage.setItem("todoList",JSON.stringify(todoList))` to store it and when the page loads, you need `const todoList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todoList") || '[]')` to initialise the list - this is needed only ONCE